# Lightning component quick action - send parameters to the lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a lightning component that is available for use as lightning component quick action.

I need to use this component from various object actions, for example, I will add a lightning component quick action to account object and to contact object.

Now on the lightning component itself, I want to know if it was invoked from the account object or from the contact object, but I cannot find a way to do that.

I have found a way to get the record Id by adding `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />` (see code snippet below)

It is working but not good enough.

What I really need is to send a parameter from the lightning component quick action invocation:
[image]

And get it in my component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="param" type="String"/>
</aura:component>
```

Is this possible?

And if not - any workaround for achieving that?

Comment: I don't think you can. Can't you query it without  h the record id ?

Comment: query what? how do I query the quick action that invoked the component?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What kind of parameter do you want to add ? It's not a value related to your contact record ?

Comment: It's not related to the contact record. I want to pass the button name

Comment: Ok, so I don't think you can do it. If you want to use the same component on 2 different buttons, I guess you'll need to create 2 separates wrapper components, one for each button. You'll be able to use your initial components with different attributes this way. Not exactly what you wanted but I don't see any other way for now.

Comment: @FabienTaillon's is correct, the above approach is the only way to do it. Fabien, Please post the comment as the answer, so that it can help others.

Comment: Done @Praveen :)

Comment: Are you able to use the `force:hasSObjectName` interface to get the API name of the object? I have not tried this with quick actions but it has worked for me elsewhere. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm

Comment: Thanks @D.S. I have tried that, but I do not get the object name at the client controller, also - in that document they say: "The sObjectName attribute is populated only when you place the component on a record page. In all other cases, such as when you create this component programmatically inside another component, sObjectName isn’t populated, and your component shouldn’t depend on it." so I think this is not possible.

Comment: I would think that a lightning quick action would count as a record detail page context, but it sounds like that is not the case which is unfortunate.

Comment: This feature is not available for now - please vote for this feature [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRQMQA2)

Comment: @ItaiShmida Also, it is a bad idea to add an attribute recordId and use force:hasRecordId. It can cause issues if you're not careful.

Comment: @sfdcfox do you mean put them together in the same component? I do this in all my components (in the past it was a must), should I change my components?

Comment: @ItaiShmida Yes, read force:hasRecordId in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky workaround to pass one parameter (besides record Id) is to name the quick action API name like so:
**ParamVal_XXX_QuickActionName**

Example: a quick action with API Name **Foo_XXX_Quickie** created on Account object

Then in your LWC, you can parse the Param Value off the quick action API name like so:

```
import { api, wire } from "lwc";
import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";
............

@wire(CurrentPageReference)
parseParam(CurrentPageReference){
    if (currentPageReference.type === "standard__quickAction") {
        let quickActionPath = currentPageReference.attributes.apiName; // Account.Foo_XXX_Quickie
        let paramValue = quickActionPath.split(".")[1].split("_XXX_")[0]; // Foo
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice workaround @snippet69, although it is not exactly sending params, it can differentiate between the different actions the are using the LWC. thank you for sharing this!

Comment: I have added this to my Quick Action LWC but it is only returning the API Name of the record page - not the Quick Action.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do it. If you want to use the same component on 2 different buttons, you'll need to create 2 separates wrapper components, one for each button. You'll be able to use your initial component with different attributes this way. Not exactly what you wanted but I don't see any other way for now.

Comment: I did not find any other workable solution. I have also tried with a little hacking to get the button's css class with this: `document.getElementsByClassName` command but it did not work - look at my other question: [How to get an html element through it's class name in a lightning component controller](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155424/how-to-get-an-html-element-through-its-class-name-in-a-lightning-component-cont). So I am marking this answer as best

Comment: please vote for this feature [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRQMQA2)

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible, you will need to use apex to get the object type from the recordId.

From there you can pass it back to the JS controller and then decide on what to do with it then.

See here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-find-Object-Type-from-Record-ID-Prefix&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "lightning:isUrlAddressable" to access a lightning component using an url and create a "Detail Page Link" with behavior as "Display in existing window without sidebar or header" that directs you to the component URL, as mentioned in the documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation

The URL in the detail link should look like below:

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/cmp/namespace__componentName', null, [param=value])}
```

NOTE: Look for the detail link in the "Custom Links" section of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly. But if you wanna know which object is calling the lightning component, you could check its Id's prefix. Each object has its own Id prefix, por instance:

ID Prefix -> Object Type:

001 -> Account

002 -> Note

003 -> Contact

Or you could use this method to get the object name by its Id:

Id sampleid = '00561000000Mjya';

System.debug('object is '+ sampleid.getsobjecttype());

So, you could pass any object's Id as parameter to the lightning component, and check its Id prefix to get the correct object and change the logic accordingly.

Comment: And just how do you pass the Object's Id from a Quick Action?
That's the whole point of the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `force:hasSObjectName` to your component implements list and then use that in your `doInit`

Add to your component:

```
<aura:attribute name="sobjecttype" type="String" default="{!v.sObjectName}"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
```

And in your doInit:

```
({doInit: function(component, event, helper){        
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var sObjectType = component.get("v.sobjecttype");

    if(recId && sObjectType === 'Account') {}
    if(recId && sObjectType === 'Contact') {}        
}})
```

Comment: Your solution will work only for the object type. But I need other parameters to send, not the object type

Comment: @ItaiShmida My solution covers one part of your question: " Now on the lightning component itself, I want to know if it was invoked from the account object or from the contact object, but I cannot find a way to do that." 

Regarding other parameters, can you not query the server side and pass the recordId as argument? You should be able to retrieve any params you want.