# How to get an HTML element through its class name in a lightning component controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to get an HTML element through its class name within in a lightning component controller.

Something that will work like `document.getElementsByClassName`

`component.find("aura:id")` won't help me - I need to get an existing html element, not something that I am generating.

I use this component from within a lightning component quick action on the contact object:

Markup:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <div class="myTest" title="testTitle" >
        <div class="test2" >
            test
            <a href="test" >test</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myTest");
        console.log("elements.length: " + elements.length);
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
})
```

And I get an empty array - `elements.length` is 0.

Is there any option?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`init` handler is called long before DOM is rendered in the view by the component. The appropriate place to access DOM, is in **Renderer**.

Add  `afterRender` method which in turn gets called once the DOM rendering is done:

```
    afterRender : function(cmp,helper){
        this.superAfterRender();
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myTest");
        console.log("elements.length: " + elements.length);
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried to do that, and I can get the element class from within my component successfully. But when I try to get an element from outside my component (I am inside a lightning component quick action), I get an empty array. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @ItaiShmida Where are actually accessing the DOM, is like you are trying to access the child component's DOM from your parent component(i.e which is quick action component)?. If this is the actual issue, then you should included this info in the question. Only if you include scenario which details the actual problem,  we could help you better.

Comment: Thanks for my current question - you have answered it and the answer is good. what I am trying to achieve is this [Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155267/lightning-component-quick-action-send-parameters-to-the-lightning-component?noredirect=1#comment229013_155267) and I understand it is not possible. Thanks for all your help

Comment: this is not working with lockerservice on