# How to implement an Apex-backed Action button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, action

Is there a leaner way (less code) of implementing an Apex-backed custom button in the Lightning record UI than creating a "full" component per Action?

Comment: I have also tried to find a solution to this problem, but could not. Eventually, I have created a base component that for each new apex command I would create a new lightning component to inherit from. Also I have an apex class that this base component uses as a controller - to execute all apex methods. And in each new component I set an attribute that states the apex method name. My question is here: (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155267/lightning-component-quick-action-send-parameters-to-the-lightning-component)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want to implement a "full" lifecycle of a standalone, self-contained Lightning Component for every action button (say each one has to call Apex individual, doing the same kind of visualization, etc.).
I hope that I understand your need the right way, my idea would be an abstract base class which has all common shared code and visualization like this:

**BaseActionButton.cmp**

```
<aura:component abstract="true" extensible="true" access="global" implements="force:hasRecordId"
controller="ActionButtonController">

<!-- 
  attributes 
-->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="global"
    description="Holds quote SFDC ID if present." />

<!-- 
  attributes - privates (because of inheritance must be access="public") for concrete implementations
-->
<aura:attribute name="iconName" type="String" access="global" 
    description="SLDS icon name, like utility:upload." />

<aura:attribute name="label" type="String" access="global" 
    description="The label used for the button and alternative text." />


<aura:attribute name="actionAPIName" type="String" access="public" 
    description="Action name for apex controller"/>


<!-- 
  body 
-->
<lightning:button class="slds-button-halfwidth slds-truncate" 
          onclick="{!c.onActionButtonClick}"
          variant="neutral" 
          iconName="{!v.iconName}" 
          label="{!v.label}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**BaseActionButtonController.js**

```
({
    /**
     * action button click action
     */
    onActionButtonClick: function (component) {
        helper.processAction(component);
    }
)}
```

**BaseActionButtonHelper.js**

```
({
    /**
     * action button processing
     */
    processAction: function (component) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var actionAPIName = component.get("v.actionAPIName");
        var params = {"recordId": recordId, "action": actionAPIName};
        //your default aura action code goes here - same call for all buttons
        [...]

    }
)}
```

**DeclineActionButton.cmp**

```
<aura:component access="global" extends="c:BaseActionButton" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" 
    description="Concrete Button">

    <!-- 
      set attributes from super class
    -->
    <aura:set attribute="actionAPIName" value="decline" />
    <aura:set attribute="iconName" value="utility:dislike" />
    <aura:set attribute="label" value="{!$Label.c.Btn_Decline}" />

    <!-- 
      no body, rendered from super class
    -->

</aura:component>
```

Now you can add all concrete ActionButtons on the record page.
Probably this idea helps to minimize boilerplate code.