# Any way to allow user to select design component options when using a quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

Given a lightning component with a design component included and said lightning component is used in a quick action....

Is there any way for the sf admin creating the quick action to set the values of said design attributes for the quick action?

I know this can be done if the component was placed in the page layout but the component is designed as a quick action and not meant to be in the page layout.

Just in case this is not possible, I created an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003UqXQAU) that can be voted on.

Use Case for the above:

1. Quick action makes a callout (Apex controller) that requires a specific property value to be sent. (ex. "I", "O", or "H")
2. Said property can be 1 of 3 values and needs to be specified to determine the types of records the endpoint returns. While it does not typically change within an org it could change between orgs
3. Thus a design component specifies the options and the user chooses which value to set the property to when definining the quick action
4. When quick action is executed, the property is set to the choosen value.

Right now all we can do is default the value which make it tough to implement for a large customer base.

Current workaround is to use a custom setting, but that requires significantly more work expecially if there are differing values for different recordtypes, objects, etc.

Update:

Had to abandon the quick action because the size of the modal could not be increased. No way to get a handle on the DOM for the modal. Had to go with a first class component.

Please vote for this idea as well: [Allow customizing width of quick action popup window in Lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E6ocQAC)

Comment: This is not possible - had the same question a while ago: [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155267/lightning-component-quick-action-send-parameters-to-the-lightning-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155267/lightning-component-quick-action-send-parameters-to-the-lightning-component)