# How to get Quick Action name?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have created 3 quick actions using 1 lightning controller.If one action button is clicked then i have perform operations if other then perform some other operation.

But I have to implement all these in a single Lightning controller.
In order to do this i need the quick action name to know which action to perform.
Please help me on how to get the quick action name in lightning controller?

Comment: I have asked this question 2 years ago and it was not possible to achieve without wrapper components - still is today - here is [my question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155267/lightning-component-quick-action-send-parameters-to-the-lightning-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create wrapper components and use it to pass parameters to your common component.
Expose the main wrapper components as quick actions.

There is an open [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRQMQA2) for this SF idea exchange

something like below

```
<c:deactivatewrapper>
<c:activationdeactivationcomponent operation="deactivate"/>
</c:deactivatewrapper>

<c:activatewrapper>
<c:activationdeactivationcomponent operation="activate"/>
</c:activatewrapper>

<c:activatewrapper>
<c:activationdeactivationcomponent operation="onhold"/>
</c:activatewrapper>
```